# how to add headers from datatable to datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

***Question edited***

I have a `datatable`that repeatedly fill by user selection (but the headers of `datatable` don't change) , using this code I add it's data to a `datagridview` but the problem is the header of `datatable` (at
 least 50 header that I don't want to add them manually) do not add as well.

```
public static void GetSelectedFeed(Form2 frm2)
{
    if (frm2.FeedSelectListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
        OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FeedLibrary where ID =" + frm2.FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue, Connection);
        DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
        DataA.Fill(DTable);

        frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.ColumnCount = DTable.Columns.Count;

        foreach (DataRow DR in DTable.Rows)
        {
            frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.Rows.Add(DR.ItemArray);
        }

        frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
        frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = true;
        frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.Columns[1].Frozen = true;

        frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
    }
}
```

How could I programatically add headers of `DataTable` to `dataGridView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how the headers of `datatable` should add to a `datagridview`

```
for (int k = 0; k < DTable.Columns.Count; k++)
{
    frm2.SelectedFeeddataGridView.Columns.Add(DTable.Columns[k].ColumnName, DTable.Columns[k].Caption);
}
```